# Node on the ends of an arrow sign

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-node

[image]

I have a plot where I have 2 arrows with nodes. For the red one I used `\draw [<-,red,line width=0.6pt] (6,8) -- (30,8) node [right,black,draw=red,fill=white] {$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{3}{2}$};` command, which produced a left pointing arrow with the node on its right end. I used the command `\draw [->,blue,line width=0.6pt] (0.6,8) -- (3,8) node [left,black,draw=blue,fill=white] {$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{5}{2}$};` for the blue one, but it didn't result in a right pointing arrow with the node on its left end. Can someone, please, explain it to me why it didn't work and how can I fix it? Below is the full code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    width=8cm,
    height=6cm,
    axis line style={line width=0.6pt},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xmin=0.1,xmax=1000,
    xtick={0.1,1,10,100,1000},
    xtick align=inside,
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    ytick={0,2,...,10},
    ytick align=inside,
]

\addplot [red,line width=0.6pt,domain=0.1:10,samples=200] {3*x/2};
\addplot [blue,line width=0.6pt,domain=0.1:10,samples=200] {5*x/2};

\draw [<-,red,line width=0.6pt] (6,8) -- (30,8) node [right,black,draw=red,fill=white] {$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{3}{2}$};
\draw [->,blue,line width=0.6pt] (0.6,8) -- (3,8) node [left,black,draw=blue,fill=white] {$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{5}{2}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason the image isn't displayed.  Sorry about that. It never happened before and I cannot fix it.

Comment: with `\draw [->,blue,line width=0.6pt] (0.6,8) node [left,black,draw=blue,fill=white] {$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{5}{2}$}-- (3,8) ;``

Comment: @pascal974 Your comment is a good answer! Post is as an answer.

Comment: @pascal974 thanks a lot!

Comment: You put the node on the right end of the line that points to the right. The node is covering the line. Out the node behind the start coordinate or reverse the coordinates (and the tip specification). Though, I'd use the canvas coordinate system for the length of the arrow or even a pin since you want the lines to have the same length. No need to mess around with the logarithmic axis cs.